# pthread_create - error when compiling in c

Tags: pthreads

When I try to compile this I get an error:

> warning: passing argument 1 of `pthread_create` makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Please if anyone can help me..

```
    int Traveler(int id, int numBags)
    {
           int i;
           int err;
         err = pthread_create(id, NULL, Traveler, NULL);
         if(err!=0)
         {
                      return -1;
         }
         else
         {

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is pretty clear. The first argument should be a pointer rather than an integer.

man pthread:

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
          const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
          void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *restrict arg);

   The  pthread_create()  function  shall  create  a  new   thread,   with
   attributes  specified  by  attr, within a process. If attr is NULL, the
   default attributes shall be used. If the attributes specified  by  attr
   are modified later, the thread's attributes shall not be affected. Upon
   successful completion, pthread_create() shall store the ID of the  cre-
   ated thread in the location referenced by thread.
```

Re-read that last sentence before sticking an ampersand before `id` in your pthread_create call. EDIT2: you will also have to define `id` as a pthread_t.

EDIT:

Actually, there are two other issues on the same line: start_routine needs to be a function that takes one argument rather than two, but worst of all this would be a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) since you're passing the same function you're calling from!

Comment: +1, but sticking an `&` in front of `id` isn't the right thing to do - the first argument needs to be a pointer to a `pthread_t` not a pointer to an `int`. The compiler might accept it (if `pthread_t` happens to be a typedef for an `int`), but not in general.

Comment: Good catch. Have updated my answer. Well, I guess that makes 4 errors in one line... :-)